# What does hieroglyphs means on this photo of cat figure? (Characters identified: 招財進寶 and 福)

Tags: character-identification

[image]

Translate please. I know I need to learn Сhinese, but I always have little time for such a difficult task...

Comment: See also [招财、招福, why cats?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/6537/8099)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

招财进宝 is the same as 招进财宝, which means recruit treasure.

福 means to live happily and fortunately

Comment: Thanks. You're great.

Answer (score 1):

**日文(Japanese):** 招き猫; **中文(Chinese):** 招财猫; **英文(English):** Fortune cats

[image]

https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%8B%9B%E8%B2%A1%E8%B2%93